# Connection Arduino on Google Colab

Tags: arduino, google-colaboratory

I have tried to connect Arduino Uno to Python code on Colaboratory, to send information to the Arduino using Pysireal library, but I didn't success, I kept reserve this Error on Colab:
" SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port COM5: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'COM5' "
I'm sure that this port is connected, but Colab can't find the port because it’s on local environment.
What can I do to solve this Error ?? is there any way that can I connect my Arduino to Google Colab ?
Hakam Salti.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The Colab instance is connected to computer on the Google cloud (unless you've set up a local instance): the code doesn't execute on your machine, your typing code into a web interface that remotely runs that code, returns the result and it gets displayed back on that interface.

The Arduino is connected to your computer (a PC by the looks of the serial port).

Your question doesn't specify which way the data goes: send Arduino data to Colab, send Colab data to Arduino or bidirectional.

If you had a WIFI connected microcontroller, you could push the data online through an [API, like Firebase](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/electropeak/connecting-arduino-to-firebase-to-send-receive-data-cd8805)

For USB, you'd need this sort of connection:

```
Arduino (OS/serial driver) <-> Browser <-> Colab
```

To connect the Arduino to the browser you'd need to use [WebSerial](https://web.dev/serial/) or an app that has serial access that can also act as a web server (such as a WebSocket server). Since you're using Python for colab you can write a script on your PC that uses [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and a websocket server such as [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html), [Flask](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), etc. ([p5.js](https://github.com/p5-serial/p5.serialport) does something like this with electron in JS and they have [prebuilt apps](https://github.com/p5-serial/p5.serialcontrol/releases))

The second part is getting that data which is now available to your browser, but locally, available to the Colab notebook. There are multiple ways of doing this, but [this WebCam example](https://colab.research.google.com/github/a2kiti/webCamGoogleColab/blob/master/webCamGoogleColab_websocketVersion.ipynb#scrollTo=Nz6ugi6mJ8EZ) looks like a good starting point.

Another variant of this might be:

1. Write a local script that acts as basic web server (http/websocket) and can access the serial port
2. make that local web server acessible from the internet ([ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs) can help here)
3. access that websocket version from python (via a websocket client or http client pip package)

**Update** I've posted a couple of options using p5.serialport [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72860987/how-to-use-p5-js-serial-library-in-google-colab/72862874#72862874).

For reference here are a couple of tested options using the afore mentioned p5.serial (and it's p5.serialcontrol utility):

Option 1: use Jupyter's HTML feature to run client side code (p5.serial) connecting to the p5.serialcontrol utility on your computer:

```py
from google.colab import files
from IPython.display import HTML, Audio
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode
C_HTML = """
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5.serialserver@0.0.29/lib/p5.serialport.js" onload="setupSerial();" onerror="console.warn(e)";></script>
<script>

const serialPort = 'COM13';

let serial;
let isOn = false;

function setupSerial(){
  serial = new p5.SerialPort();
  serial.open(serialPort);
  
  setInterval(blink, 1000);
  console.log("serial setup complete");
}

function blink(){
  isOn = !isOn;
  if(serial){
    serial.write(isOn ? '1' : '0');
  }
}

serialInterval = setInterval(checkSerial,500);

function checkSerial(){
  console.log('p5.SerialPort',p5.SerialPort);
  if(p5.SerialPort){
    clearInterval(serialInterval);
    setupSerial();
  }
}
</script>
"""

def run():
  display(HTML(C_HTML))

run()
```

Option 2: use a reverse tunnel (`ngrok`) to have the Python side connect to p5.serialcontrol via WebSockets (though you'd need to compose the messages p5.serialcontrol expects maually):

1. run p5.serialcontrol
2. run `ngrok tcp 8081` from Terminal/Command Prompt (**note** you may need to setup a free to use auth token for TCP)
3. install webocket-client on Colab and connect to the websocket (**note** as opposed to using the p5.serial library in JS, you'd manually put together the messaages to send to p5.serialcontrol's websocket server (e.g. `'{"method":"openserial","data":{"serialport":"COM13","serialoptions":{}}}'` to open the serial port, `'{"method":"write","data":"1"}'` to write '1' to serial, etc.))

To install websocket-client in colab you'd use:

```
!pip install -q websocket-client
```

and here's an example that turns on LED on for 1 second then off (using the above Arduino example):

```py
from time import sleep
import websocket

# when the websocket is open send a serial open command (on port COM13) then send a '1' then a '0' with 1 second in between
def on_open(ws):
  ws.send('{"method":"openserial","data":{"serialport":"COM13","serialoptions":{}}}')
  sleep(1)
  print('sending ON')
  wsapp.send('{"method":"write","data":"1"}')
  sleep(1)
  print('sending OFF')
  wsapp.send('{"method":"write","data":"0"}')

def on_message(ws, message):
  print(message)

def on_error(wsapp, err):
  print("Got a an error: ", err)

wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://YOUR_NGROK_TCP_SERVER_HERE",
# YOUR_NGROK_TCP_SERVER_HERE example #.tcp.ngrok.io:#####,
  on_message = on_message,
  on_error=on_error)
wsapp.on_open = on_open

wsapp.run_forever()
```

(also note `run_forever()` is a blocking loop: based on your application you may want to manually run open and control a websocket connection (as opposed to using WebSocketApp) or [use threading](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), depending on what makes)

Comment: My guess is this is going to be too advanced to follow for most people without an explicit demo.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Thank you for the feedback. I've spotted another similar question and posted an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72860987/how-to-use-p5-js-serial-library-in-google-colab/72862874#72862874